# How to view ediff (and other) manuals within emacs?

Tags: ediff, manual

I want to learn how to use a built in package (e.g. ediff). This built-in package has an online manual in html, but presumably this content is also available from within emacs.

How do I view it within emacs?

Aside: I have also tried to find the pdf for the ediff manual (for offline reading), but cannot find it. The solution to the above problem would solve it, but it would also be good to know if / how I can find / create a pdf of an emacs builtin package.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs comes with comprehensive documentation in the form of GNU Info pages.  To access these press `C-h i` which will take you to the toplevel menu of major topics which ought to include Emacs, the Emacs FAQ, Info, and many others.  Press 'm' to search for a named info node.  Enter (say) "ediff" and you'll be taken to the Ediff documentation.

Alternatively given a command you could use `C-h F` to search the documentation, which in this case if you enter 'ediff' will also drop you into the Ediff documentation.

This being Emacs of course there are also many other ways :-)

Comment: Also see [`helm-info`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Info-Files) for the Helm interface to Info files.